# Why web3.version.api shows undefined for web3 1.0 and not undefined for web3 0.20.3?

Tags: web3js, metamask, web3js-v1.x, web3js-v0.x

I'm trying to use MetaMask and web3js to talk to my smart contract. Below are my test codes.

This is without defining a web3 js file and I get the result "0.20.3" at console.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
    if (typeof web3 !== "undefined") {
      // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      var version = web3.version.api;
      console.log(version);
    } else {
      console.log("No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!");
      // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
      window.web3 = new Web3(
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://localhost:8545")
      );
    });
</script>
```

And this is with defining a web3 1.0 beta-34 file. But I get "undefined" at console.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Check if Web3 has been injected by the browser:
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            // You have a web3 browser! Continue below!
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

            var version = web3.version.api;
            console.log(version); // "0.2.0"

            startApp(web3);

        } else {
            alert("No hay web3");
            // Warn the user that they need to get a web3 browser
            // Or install MetaMask, maybe with a nice graphic.
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Peter's explaination, If you have metamask extension installed on your chrome and logged in, open the console and type `web3.version.api`you will get "0.20.3" as this is the version of web3 injected by metamask. This is what happens when you try the first time => "This is without defining a web3 js file and I get the result "0.20.3" at console"

In your second attempt, you are checking the validity of the web3.

`if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined')`

This web3 is the one injected by metamask. Not the one from your script. Later you update this

`web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider)`

If you comment this line, you will get console output as "0.20.3". After this line is executed, `web3` variable is now having the Web3 instance of version "1.0.0-beta.34". So you need to use `web3.version`

Also, If you add a script file, ideally you should use the api as per usage definitions of that version

Answer (score 0):

They had changed lots of apis in beta version of web3.

If you want to know the version of web3.js, you can use `web3.version` or check the version from package.json:

```
import { version } from 'web3/package.json';
```

If you want to know version of api protocol, check this (source code from v0.2):

```
return [
        new Property({
            name: 'version.node',
            getter: 'web3_clientVersion'
        }),
        new Property({
            name: 'version.network',
            getter: 'net_version',
            inputFormatter: utils.toDecimal
        }),
        new Property({
            name: 'version.ethereum',
            getter: 'eth_protocolVersion',
            inputFormatter: utils.toDecimal
        }),
        new Property({
            name: 'version.whisper',
            getter: 'shh_version',
            inputFormatter: utils.toDecimal
        })
];
```

Each version of protocol is a JSONRPC call.